# I ecounter this error all the time in node.js. Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn node.js and these are my files and errors. I don't know what actually is wrong. I am learning a tutorial from Programming with Moss.

app.js

```
var logger = require('./logger');

console.log(logger);
```

logger.js

```
function log() {
    console.log("hello");
}

module.exports.log = log;
```

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1017
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './logger'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\pshre\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs demo\first-app\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:15)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pshre\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs demo\first-app\app.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\pshre\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\nodejs demo\\first-app\\app.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
var logger = require('/logger');
```

Use

```
var logger = require('./logger'); //Notice the dot there
```

To put it simply the dot references the current path, so if you path is something like `/home/user/project` it would point to the `/home/user/project/logger.js` file.

EDIT: Make sure your app.js and logger.js files are in the same directory.

Comment: Did it. Still error. I have updated the code above .Please checkout.By the way i am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44b6CDDnDPg&list=PLTjRvDozrdlydy3uUBWZlLUTNpJSGGCEm&index=9

Comment: Are your logger.js and app.js files in the same directory?

Comment: Oops. they are not. Thank you. I think i was not  paying  enough attention at the file structure.

Comment: Happy to help you. If this solved your problem could you mark it as an answer, thank you :)